# pasting the name of function arguments to use within function body

Tags: r

I am trying to concatenate my function's arguments inside the body of my function for further evaluation within the bode.  I went through many code *improvements* trying to solve the issue but couldn't.

`Example:` When providing a function call like `fun(x,y)`, I want to be able to paste the characters I entered for `x`, to  `$` and the characters I entered for y to call a field within a data set for analysis.  So if I provided the characters `car` for argument `x`, and `toyota` for argument `y`, I would get `car$toyota` variable name to use within the body of the function.

I tried:

```
gtData <- function(data,field,k)
d <- diff(data$field)  ## I also tried sum(data$field) to eliminate issues with diff()
```

but `d` evaluated to `0`  ## I know it's not because when I run the code `diff(car$toyota)` I get the right answer.  I don't think its doing what I want it to do.  I also tried to paste the arguments within the body like this:

```
gtData(data,field,k)
a <- paste(data,"$",field)
```

It complained `toyota` doesn't exist because toyota is not a data set but a field in a data set.

I tried many other variation, it seems `paste()` can't do what I want it to do here.

What I am trying to get is the string `car$toyota` so I could pass it further down the body as a variable for further evaluation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is good to remember `fortune(312)`

```
The problem here is that the $ notation is a magical shortcut and like any other magic if used incorrectly
is likely to do the programmatic equivalent of turning yourself into a toad.
   -- Greg Snow (in response to a user that wanted to access a column whose name is stored in y via x$y
      rather than x[[y]])
      R-help (February 2012)
```

What you want is `[[` not `$`

```
gtData <- function(data,field,k){
  a <- data[[field]]
}
```

---

Paste is definitely the wrong thing here.

Edit  -- partial matching

If you wanted to allow partial matching, you can set the `exact` for `[[` to `FALSE` or `NA`. From `` ?`[[` ``

> Value NA allows partial matching but issues a warning when it occurs. Value FALSE allows partial matching without any warning.

and again

> x$name is equivalent to x[["name", exact = FALSE]].

---

In light of your comments. I think you need to look at the [R manuals 2.1.8](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Function-objects) and [Hadley's devtools wiki](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Functions) at how function arguments and promises

> Promise objects are part of R's lazy evaluation mechanism. They
>   contain three slots: a value, an expression, and an environment. When
>   a function is called the arguments are matched and then each of the
>   formal arguments is bound to a promise. The expression that was given
>   for that formal argument and a pointer to the environment the function
>   was called from are stored in the promise.
>
> Until that argument is accessed there is no value associated with the
>   promise. When the argument is accessed, the stored expression is
>   evaluated in the stored environment, and the result is returned. The
>   result is also saved by the promise. The substitute function will
>   extract the content of the expression slot. This allows the programmer
>   to access either the value or the expression associated with the
>   promise.

So when you pass

```
gtData(data = mtcars, field = mpg)
```

the argument `data` is a promise, which will have the value being the `mtcars` object from the  calling environment when it is accessed within the function.

If, for `field` you want to access the character string `"mpg"` not the value associated with `mpg` in the calling environment, as suggested in the manual, the idiomatic way to do this is to use `deparse(substitute())`

eg

```
gtData <- function(data,field,k){
  fieldChar <- deparse(substitute(field))
  a <- data[[fieldChar]]
}
```

The danger doing this will be if you were to then think you could  access `field` within the function, in which case it would be evaluated, and will give an error (if it doesn't exist in the calling environment), or a perhaps unintended value if it *were* defined

Comment: I can see car[["Toyota"]] works to name the field outside the body of a formula.  But when I try it inside the body it complains that the field in this case "Toyota" is not a known object.

Comment: When you pass the argument data is it `gtData(data = car,'Toyota')` or `data = 'car'`

Comment: Sorry, I ran out of time before finishing my comment, but here it is:I can see car[["Toyota"]] works to call a field outside the body of a function.  But when I try it inside the body it complains that the field in this case "Toyota" is not a known object.  I tried it with this simple code applying the sum function.  gtData <- function(dd,ff){
a  <- dd[["ff"]]
a <- sum(a)
return(a)} but it complained the field is not a known object.  I tried it without

Comment: `a <- dd[["ff"]] ` should be `a <- dd[[ff]] `, as my answer states. The extract from `?'[['` with `"name"` is just emphasising that the `name` of the column is a character string (which your argument named `field` contains)

Comment: when I call the function I am just passing car , Toyota as argument  the exact code I write to use the function is   gtData(car,toyota)

Comment: I tied the code a <- dd[[ff]] outside the function on a field I have in my data and it didn't work.  here is the code I got  a1 <- aap[[hi]]
Error: object 'hi' not found
> a1 <- y[[vol]]
Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x,  : 
  object 'vol' not found

Comment: Ok, gtData(dd=car, ff='toyota') worked.  But I don't understand why the first argument doesn't take quotes while the second needs the quotes.

Comment: See my edits and read [the manual on functions and promises](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Function-objects).

Comment: I got your comments, I will read the manual and let you know tomorrow.  but thanks for now. I think the promise/arguments idea was the missing thing in my search to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mnel, I realized using $ instead of "[" was the issue.  He also provided good reference material.

But the solution was simple.  Instead of calling the field inside the function with it's name it should be called by its number.  so data[,x] works without a problem.

thanks mnel